# Problems with axios and Azure Application Insights

Tags: node.js, axios, azure-application-insights

The NPM package `@microsoft/applicationinsights-we` from microsoft when used in the frontend will add headers for tracking calls across different parts of the application (e.g. frontend, backend, services etc.).

I'm using axios in the frontend which out of the box does not work with the package. Neither `disableFetchTracking:false` nor `disableAjaxTracking:false` works. I don't want to replace axios with fetch, because axios is more convenient to use and this would be a lot of rewrite too.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@microsoft/applicationinsights-web` package does inject correlation headers into `axios` calls (by instrumenting `XMLHttpRequest`). There might be a few causes of the problem in your application:

**Another library broke the instrumentation**

Something else might be hijacking the XMLHttpRequest object and affecting the AppInsights instrumentation. One such library is `pace.js`, which overwrites the `window.XMLHttpRequest` constructor but does not add `open`, `send` and `abort` to it's prototype. AppInsights expects these functions to be present on the `XMLHttpRequest`'s prototype: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/91f08a1171916a1bbf14c03a019ebd26a3a69b86/extensions/applicationinsights-dependencies-js/src/ajax.ts#L330

Here is a working `axios` + `@microsoft/applicationinsights-web` example:

[image: Edit axios-appinsights]

Here is the same example, but with `pace.js` loaded - the `Request-Id` header is not added:

[image: Edit axios-appinsights-pace]

Either removing `pace.js` or placing it's script tag / import after the AppInsights initialization code should fix the problem.

**Cross-origin requests**

Another explanation might be that the frontend app is making cross-origin requests, which are not processed by AppInsights by default - the `enableCorsCorrelation: true` config setting is needed.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed another package that broke it and not a missing or wrong configuration.

Comment: Your comment about AppInsights not processing cross-origin requests was extremely helpful in debugging our issue!

Comment: your examples have been deleted, this is bad, avoid using a third-party site.